# How to give step size as a range in python?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
x = e[['a','b','c','d']] 
step = 110
x_pieces = [x[i:i+step] for i in range(0, len(x), step)]
```

So, I have a data frame e and a, b ,c , d are corresponding columns in data frame.

Here, I am diving the data in steps of 110. But, I would like to specify the step size as a range and in float. Could anyone please help?

Comment: Could you clarify the question -- show us what you intend to do, possibly using pseudocode? Because I don't understand range's step parameter itself being a range, but there may be some other way to do what you want.

Comment: If you want the range to be floats, try frange on this page: https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/

Answer (score 0):

syntax is `range(start, end, step)`. Example: `range(0,100,10)`.

Here's the output as a list, using `list(range(0,100,10))` 
`[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]`

If you want it to reach 100, with stepsize=10, then add that to your range end, `list(range(0,110,10))` gives 
 `[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]`